# Raspberry/Linux doesn't recognize USB device

Tags: usb, linux, wireless-adapter

I'm using Raspberry Pi model B+ V1.2 to which I want to connect TP-LINK TL-WN823N Wireless N USB Adapter.

I have connected device and this is what happened:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=smsc95xx, 4              80M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
```

As we can see, my Raspberry Pi doesn't recognize my wireless USB adapter.

I thought it's a problem with my 1.7A power supply but I have changed to 2A PS and still it doesn't work.

Comment: This is very odd since `lsusb` reports what the devices report, i.e., no driver of any sort is required, it is simply basic USB protocol stuff.  I presume you are sure the adapter is working?  That device has several versions; one uses a RealTek 8192CU chipset for which Raspbian does include a driver, but there is no point in loading it if the device isn't even recognized (and if it were, the driver should be loaded automatically based on the chip identifying itself with the USB protocol).

Comment: Just a hunch, try installing the realtek firmware `sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek` Also share the output of `lsusb -v`. there might be some clues in there

Comment: @Shreyas Murali

lsusb -v
http://pastebin.com/MrApf3Ak


sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek
http://pastebin.com/9MJCLqy3

Comment: @ goldilocks It's a new device from the box. I have connected it to my windows PC ([Screen](https://snag.gy/32JiSI.jpg)) and I think something is wrong with device. What do you think?

Comment: @BartoszŚledź Based on the contents the `lsb -v`, it appears the dongle you have uses a Realtek chip - RTL8192E (`vendor id 0x2357 & product id 0x0109`). Given the firmware is already updated, It would be helpful to know the o/p of the `uname -a` (kernel version), `cat /etc/os-release` (os name and version), `lsmod` (currently loaded driver modules). My suspicion is some kind of kernel/driver/firmware mismatch has occured (has happened to me when applying dist-updates). If you have a spare card, could you try installing raspbian jessie (or jessie-lite) and see if the problem persists ?

Comment: @Shreyas Murali I tried installing raspbian jessie LITE - the same problem.

[Here you can find all data what you ware asked for](http://pastebin.com/Zt40qF2B)

Comment: @BartoszŚledź From the o/p i can the required driver isnt loaded.
See [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2335795) post. seems to be the same or similar problem (seems to be recent enough). One of the answers to the post links to the [source code](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver) of the device driver + some required patches. I dont know if it will build out of the box, but i think it should be worth a try. Installing some random binary blob drivers might not be stable way to keeping it updated with each kernel update.